# regex get string between start and end of match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to take classes from a css file using regex. I need to take classes between start and end of match string because most of the class are starting with the same prefix like `myy-`classname followed by its rules so i'm giving the `{` as end point, because i need to take only the class name.
 For Example

```
   .myy-foobar{
         /*CSS Rules goes here*/
         }
   .myy-anotherbar{
         /*CSS Rules goes here*/
         }
```

Now i need to take **foobar,anotherbar** using regex, so i used this preg_match_all

```
preg_match_all('/^myy-[(.*)]{$/', $file, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

To my understanding it should start with myy- so i put `^myy-` and any character between this so i used `[]` and end with { so i used `{$`

and this

```
preg_match_all('/(myy-)(.*)({)/', $file, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Here too same logic(start with myy- and any character and end with {) i tried with different syntax but nothing helps.

There are lot of classes in the file so i need to take only the middle part of all class as i know the prefix already.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code would match the text after `.myy-` upto the next `{` symbol ,

```
preg_match_all('~\.myy-\K[^{]*(?={)~', $file, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vM7wT6/3)

**OR**

The below code would match the text after `.myy-` upto the next `{` symbol or `:` symbol.

```
preg_match_all('~\.myy-\K[^{:]*(?={|:)~', $file, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vM7wT6/4)

**Explanation:**

- `\.myy-` Matches the string `.myy-`
- `\K` discards the previously matched characters.
- `[^{]*` Matches any charcter not of `{` zero or more times.
- `(?={)` Only when the following charcter must be a `{` open curly brace.`(?=)` is called **positive look-ahead**

Comment: Thanks +1 for the help. can it have two end points like. `{` as well `:`

Comment: you mean, it may be `.myy-foobar{` or `.myy-foobar:`

Comment: Yes that is what i mean

Comment: can you explain this `\K` why do we need to discard previous things as there are more classes. But we are getting all classes that is fine am just asking. How it getting all matched class even we use `\k`

Comment: so that we could get the exact match or otherwise `.myy-` would be included in the final result. Without `\K` http://regex101.com/r/vM7wT6/5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57892/discussion-between-sun-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 3):

To match just the name, use `\.myy-\K[^{\s]+(?=\s*{)`

```
$regex = '~\.myy-\K[^{\s]+(?=\s*{)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the matches in **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pS9tI3/2)**.

**Explanation**

- `\.myy-` matches `.myy-`
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `[^{\s]+` matches any chars that are not a `{` or a white-space char (this is the match)
- The lookahead `(?=\s*{)` asserts that what follows is optional whitespace chars and a `{`

To match the whole class use this: `\.myy-.*?}`

```
$regex = '~\.myy-.*?}s~';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Longest Match.** The greedy `.*` first matches the whole string, then backtracks only as far as needed to allow the next token to match. Therefore, you will often overshoot the place where you want the match to end (longest match).

**Shortest Match.** The lazy `.*?` (made "lazy" by the `?`) means that the dot only matches as many characters as needed to allow the next token to match (shortest match).

**Reference**

- [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)
- [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Comment: Yes your answer works +1. but it getting `myy` too i don't want this and i have some pseudo css class like `.myy-some:before {}` in this case i need only `some` i need to take string which ends between `{` as well `:` could that be possible?

Comment: FYI, finished tweaking the regex and added explanation. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what need but i need two end points like it may end with `{` or `:` so i stated that. @AvinashRaj given his answer for this, it works.